# bash task in Azure Devops not working on self hosted windows agent

Tags: azure-devops, windows-subsystem-for-linux, azure-devops-self-hosted-agent

Bash task is giving below error when running on self hosted windows agent -

```
Windows Subsystem for Linux has no installed distributions.

##[error]The process 'C:\Windows\system32\bash.exe' failed with exit code 1
```

Windows subsystem is installed and I can execute bask scripts by logging into agent but bash task does not work.

Happy to provide more information if required

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> bash task in Azure Devops not working on self hosted windows agent

That is because the WSL installed per a specific user, but if we run the self-hosted agent as service, it will using the `NETWORK SERVICE/SYSTEM` account instead of local user account.

You could try to set `Log On As` with the specific user (It should be the same user as you installed WSL. Then restart your server.

Detailed step for setting the Log On As with the specific user:

1. Press the Win + R keys on your keyboard, to open the Run window. Then, type “services.msc” and hit Enter or press OK.
2. Find the service for the self-hosted agent and right click it, select **Properties**, switch to **Log On** tab.
3. Change the account to the specific user.

For example, I use `xxxxxx\leoliu` account to login the server 2019:

[image]

Then install WSL with that account. After that, I open the services.msc and change the Log On As with that user:

[image]

**Last but not least**, **restart your server**, just restart the services is not enough.

Now, I could use my self-hosted agent to run the bask task:

[image]

Comment: Super grateful for this answer! can you elaborate a little more on the WSL installation? what are the steps for this installation? Thanks a lot!